# LightGBM - Estimator not fitted error after joblib.load()

Tags: machine-learning, joblib, lightgbm

I **fitted** a LGBMRegressor() model and even **predicted** some values. I decided to save it (after fit of course) to use later, but when I try to load the model I'm getting this exception:

```
Estimator not fitted, call fit before exploiting the model.
```

I tried to save in 3 different ways:

- `dump(model, 'model.txt')`
- `dump(model, 'model.pkl')`
- `dump(model, 'model.joblib')`

Then I close the IDE and tried to load like this:

- `model = joblib.load('model.allExtensionsMentionedBefore')`

When I `print(model)` I can see the entire model and also it's hyperparameters:

```
LGBMRegressor(colsample_bytree=0.9596645565436184,
              learning_rate=0.025825537313443326, min_child_samples=72,
              num_leaves=32, random_state=0, silent=True,
              subsample=0.9311181768429686, subsample_freq=1)
```

However when I try `model.predict(X)` I'm getting the exception saying that it's not fitted.

What I am doing wrong?

PS: I was able to do to this exact process (save and load) using `sklearn MLPRegressor()` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Most of the time this happens because you are saving the model from one environment thas has lightgbm version <3.3.0 and loading it into another with a lightgbm version >=3.3.1. The not fitted error can be solved with  actually the following steps : 1) Load the model: model = joblib.load(modelpath) ; 2)  Change the attribute "fitted" boolean inside the model like this : model.fitted_ = True ; 3) Then try predicting normally. It worked for me ; another alternative is making sure you have the same conda environment when you save and when you load the model (specifically, the same lgbm version)

Answer (score 2):

`lightgbm` supports saving and loading models using `joblib`.

Here's a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating how to do that. I tested this code using Python 3.3.8, `lightgbm==3.3.1`, `joblib==1.0.1`, `numpy==1.21.0` and `scikit-learn==0.24.1`.

In a new Python session:

```py
import joblib
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000, n_features=10)
reg = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    n_estimators=10,
    verbose=-1,
)

reg.fit(X, y)
joblib.dump(reg, 'lgb.pkl')
```

Then, in a separate Python session run from the same working directory:

```py
import joblib
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1_000, n_features=10)
reg = joblib.load('lgb.pkl')
preds = reg.predict(X)
```

I tried this same code using `lightgbm==3.0.0` ([from August 2020](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/releases/tag/v3.0.0)) and it worked as well.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I guess I was facing some kind of version problems. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  In my case, the problem stemmed from me saving the models in one conda environment but loading in another.  The version differences in lightgbm caused problems.  If you are using environments, make sure that you save and load your models from the same environment.